# Zend Framework: Zend_DB Error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I'm trying to learn ZF, but got strange error after 20 minutes :)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Configuration array must have a key for 'dbname' that names the database instance'
```

What does this error mean? I got DB information in my config file:

```
resources.db.adapter=pdo_mysql
resources.db.host=localhost
resources.db.username=name
resources.db.password=pass
resources.db.dbname=name
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

This is my model file /app/models/DbTable/Bands.php:

```
class Model_DbTable_Bands extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'zend_bands';
}
```

Index controller action:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $albums = new Model_DbTable_Bands();
    $this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();
}
```

EDIT
All codes:

bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
    ));
    return $autoloader;
}

protected function _initDoctype()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
}

public static function setupDatabase()
{
    $config = self::$registry->configuration;
    $db = Zend_Db::factory($config->db);
    $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
    self::$registry->database = $db;
    Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
}
```

IndexController.php

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $albums = new Model_DbTable_Bands();
        $this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

configs/application.ini, changed database and provided password:

```
[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
db.params.host = localhost
db.params.username = root
db.params.password = pedro
db.params.dbname = test
```

models/DbTable/Bands.php

```
class Model_DbTable_Bands extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'cakephp_bands';

    public function getAlbum($id) 
    {
        $id = (int)$id;
        $row = $this->fetchRow('id = ' . $id);
        if (!$row) {
            throw new Exception("Count not find row $id");
        }
        return $row->toArray();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you instantiate the db adapter? The code before and including `Zend_Db::factory( /* your config settings */ )` (I presume)

Comment: Here you are, function :)

    public static function setupDatabase()
    {
        $config = self::$registry->configuration;
        $db = Zend_Db::factory($config->db->adapter, $config->db->toArray());
        $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
        self::$registry->database = $db;
        Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
    } 

PS I don't know how to include code in comment, can anyone fix it?

Comment: Furthermore, is the config info you are showing, the literal info? If so, I don't suppose the name of your database is `name` is it? Change that to represent your database name. (along with username and password for the credentials of course)

Comment: The code looks ok. See my previous assumptions. (Use backticks \` for code in comments.)

Comment: This is my test server db name is zend, username is root without password. Have no idea what could be wrong with it. Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: How do you execute `setupDatabase()`? Are you sure this is executed (at all) before you try to create the model?

Answer (score 1):

To maybe finally conclude this discussion with the correct solution, here is mine:

application.ini:

```
resources.db.adapter = mysqli
resources.db.params.dbname = zftutorial
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = juuro
resources.db.params.password = test
```

The string `params` was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`public static function setupDatabase()`

With

`protected function _initDatabase()`

...and try again

I presume you are simply not calling the static method you have defined. But when you create a protected method starting with `_init` it is automatically executed when bootstrapping.

PS.:
You probably really want to assign a password to the root user of your database, even if it's a test server. Just to be save. If someone is able to access your testserver, you could expose valuable customer info if you don't have a password. `root` is the first user they will try. Better still, would be to assign a different user/pass combo to each individual database.

Comment: You see, I'm providing correct data:`resources.db.adapter=pdo_mysql
resources.db.host=localhost
resources.db.username=root
resources.db.password=
resources.db.dbname=zend`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are not running the app with the correct value in the `APPLICATION_ENV`environment var and then it trying to load a different part of the config file instead of `development:production`

Check that you are running your web application under the correct environment var

- For Apache put this inside of your `<virtualhost>`

  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
- Also you can try to force de `APPLICATION_ENV` var in your index.php